# Dealing with CORS in Node / express static file

Tags: node.js, express, cors

Trying to deal with CORS set up a simple Node / Express server like so:

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server active on port: ', port);
});
```

Using this cors lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

The rest is a simple app using JQuery ajax to fetch some data... Works with the CORS chrome extension enabled but can't figure out how to set up a simple server so that I do not have to use the chrome extension...

Comment: So, What error you receive in your console, when you turn off your chrome extension?

Comment: Before I set up the server I was using the extension and it was working just fine... set up the server and using the lib in order not use the extension. The error is: Allow origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin ‘http//localhost:3000’ is therefore not allowed access...

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: @SakoBu can you paste the exact error? Are you saying that the Allow origin header is present or is it not present? Also add the error after disabling CORS. Try opening in incognito tab as well since chrome caches CORS headers.

Answer (score 1):

You may try setting the options to be passed to your `cors` package, like this,

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: process.env.CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried... no dice... It's really got me stumped... Tried lib, no lib... Posted the same question as an issue with the lib creator... maybe he'll let me know...

Comment: I can try something like this: app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
}); see if that works...

Answer (score -1):

You can use a cors middleware like this

```
 const corsMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  logger.debug(req.method + " at " + req.url);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // you can optionally replace * with your server address
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );

  next();
};
```

To use this middleware for all kinds of requests, use

```
app.all("*", corsMiddleware);
```

This will add these headers in all the requests.

Comment: Since the OP uses cors package, there is no need to send additional headers I believe.

Comment: @DavidR apparently cors is not working with OP beacuse in the question he says that he needs to use chrome cors plugin. I used to face the same issue where cors plugin on chrome rewrote the headers set by server. In that case the op needs to remove cors plugin and try this way I guess